# CompileErrors in C using header files

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header-files

I am learning how to program in C.

I am getting the following errors. I have tried to rewrite my code several times but I simply do not understand what to do in this situation. Help is very much appreciated. Down below I have listed the compile errors and all the files included in the project and their sourcecode.
[image]
main.c

```
#include "ports.h"
#include "KeyboardML15.h"

int main(){
  int get_key(void);
  return 0;
}
```

KeyboardML15.c

```
int get_key(void){

  int msbSet;   


  while(1)(

    msbSet = MSB & Key_Decode_Register:
    if(msbSet){
        return Key_Decode_Register;
    }
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

Keyboard.h

```
int get_key(void);
```

ports.h

```
#define IRQ_VECADR  0x3FF2
#define IRQ_VEC     *((vecptr) IRQ_VEQ_ADR)

#define set(x, mask)    (x) = (x) | (mask)
#define clear(x, mask)  (x) = (x) & ~(mask)


typedef unsigned char * port8ptr;
typedef unsigned short * port16ptr;
typedef unsigned long *port32ptr;

unsigned char ML4shadow = 0;
unsigned char MSB = 128

#define ML4OUT_ADDRESS 0x400
#define ML4OUT *((port8ptr) ML4OUT_ADDRESS)

#define ML4IN_ADDRESS 0x600
#define ML4IN *((port8ptr) ML4IN_ADDRESS)

#define Key_Decode_Register_ADDRESS 0x9C0
#define Key_Decode_Register *((port8ptr) Key_Decode_Register);



#ifdef SIMULATOR
  #define DRILLSTATUS_ADDRESS 0x401
#else
  #define DRILLSTATUS_ADDRESS 0x600
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems a type in your code below:

```
msbSet = MSB & Key_Decode_Register:
while(1)(
```

Change it to

```
msbSet = MSB & Key_Decode_Register;
while(1){
    if(msbSet){
        return Key_Decode_Register;
    } else {
        //dont you want to return? or else you will end up running in infinite loop
    }
```

Comment: I have made a change in the code. So that the msbSet is constantly reinitiated. It was supposed to be inside the while loop. That said , the problem lies in the fact that The defined statements in ports.h cannot be found and I do not now what else I can do to make it visible in the files.

Comment: The idea is that a button is pressed and when that happens its supposed to be shown on a display later. Therefore the infinity while loop. We are basically waiting for a button to be pressed and constantly read until that happens